# How to evaluate $\pm$ operations

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation

When finding the root of a number with an even exponent, $x^y$ becomes $\pm x$.  How would this work in a situation such as $a = \sqrt{(5x + 12)^2 + m}$?  I know that the result is not $a = \pm 5x + 12 + \sqrt m$ because the parentheses must be evaluated first.

Could anybody please tell me how to evaluate the answer to this problem correctly?

Comment: I'm having trouble with the tags trying to find a tag that will accurately represent this question.  Could somebody please edit the tags to better reflect this?  I tried searching for ones related to precedence, and the closest I found was exponentiation, which, for all intents and purposes, is probably close enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the notation $\sqrt [n] x$, for positive $x$ and even $n$, refers specifically to the *positive* $n$th root of $x$. So evaluating $a$ as you've written it does not require any $\pm$s whatsoever. You are absolutely correct that you cannot just add together the square roots of the individual terms—in fact, the expression you've given is about as good as any; if you like you can expand the squared term, but that won't actually simplify anything.

If you're trying to solve the equation $a^2=(5x+12)^2+m$ for $a$, you will get $a=\pm\sqrt{(5x+12)^2+m}$.